# VirtualDocumentRoot and domains always routing to localhost - why?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts, document-root

I'm trying to get dynamic virtual hosts to work, followed the documentation but it didn't quite work.

These are the domains from my HOSTS file:

```
127.0.0.1 walestourism.local.co.uk
127.0.0.1 www.walestourism.local.co.uk
127.0.0.2 walestourism.local.co.uk
127.0.0.2 www.walestourism.local.co.uk
```

and this is from httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.2
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>
ServerName www.walestourism.local.co.uk
ServerAlias walestourism.local.co.uk
DocumentRoot /www/walestourism.local.co.uk
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/walestourism.local.co.uk/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>
```

In all my other ones it was always *:80 for the VirtualHost  part of the above code.

I have this code in my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory C:/www/vhosts>   
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory C:/www/vhosts1>   
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory C:/www/vhosts.www>   
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory C:/www/test2>   
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory C:/www/>   
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

How should I fix this error, as when I type the domain in it takes me to the contents of http://localhost ? That's the basic problem I get when I try to add domains using dynamic virtual hosts.

Also, if I point my browser to "http://localhost/", I get the default "It Works!" page, so I know that my server is running and that this is definitely something to do with the vhosts configuration.

I checked my error log - no errors as a result of this, so why does every domain direct to localhost even when there's a folder configured for them (/www/ in this case is C:/www, my Apache/webserver's directory).

I'm new to this area of Apache, and despite an afternoon of Googling, I'm not sure how to fix this.

I decided to try this to avoid doing cmd > httpd -k restart every time I add a new virtualhost for testing, but have I done anything wrong?

I'm on Apache 2.2, using Windows 7, with PHP 5.28 [mentioning specifications here].

What should I do?

All advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using named based virtual hosting, don't use 127.0.0.2 ... just keep it all to 127.0.0.1 ... failing that, check the error_log for apache (defined in your httpd.conf) to trouble shoot why it is failing.

Additionally, get Apache2 working on Windows with VHosts *before* you get going with PHP ...

As per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html:

```
 # Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
 Listen 80

 # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
 NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/example1
 ServerName www.example1.com
 # Other directives here
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/example2
 ServerName www.example2.org
 # Other directives here
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache works well anyway, it's just name-based ones that I'm new to. Do I need to remove 127.0.0.2 from <VirtualHost> ?

Comment: amended with the right configuration.  this will be applicable to all bound interfaces for apache

Comment: Thanks! As for name-based virtual hosting, I guess that means no more httpd -k restart to keep restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens, if a virtual host is configured wrongly. As you are on windows I have no idea how to test your configuration, on linux you would do something like:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd configtest
```

try to start apache from command line and see if you get any errors. If Apache is installed as  a service you can see startup errors in the windows application event logs.